# Will factory resetting make my rooted device unbootable?

Tags: factory-reset

I rooted my Samsung Galaxy Core 3 Plus running Android 4.3 with Kingoroot and now I want to factory reset it. Is it safe to do that?

I am using the stock ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its safe to do factory reset.

However, I once tried this below approach and **bricked my phone**. So beware.

If you're using a custom recovery like TWRP and choose complete wipe.

> (*Advanced wipe -> select all options including Internal, system
>   ,etc*)

This **erases the complete phone**.
So after erase if you do not install a new custom rom immediately (without reboot), your phone goes into infinite loop.

You'll now be stuck with a phone which keeps restarting as **no ROM's are available on the phone memory either because of the wipe**.

Worst part, My phone didn't have an external SD card so I couldn't copy any other ROM into the phone and to install it later.

> My Suggestion : Just be sure of the options you select during Wipe.

Comment: Thanks! I did a factory reset on my phone without any problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can do factory reset. You device would not get into a bootloop because  rooting is a method that  installs the  superuser apk in system apps and  gives you extra privileges . I didn't think that that it is not safe  Still, I performed factory reset 100 times on my  Android phone and nothing happened.

Comment: sorry auto-correct  i mean it install the superuser apk on the system site so it won't  be uninstalled  when you do Factory  reset so that for you would  be still rooted but you can do factory resets  hope i help you sorry for my grammar mistakes   

Comment: Is there a good reason you deliberately messed up with punctuation?

Comment: Supper than have a andorid day :D